# Azure AD B2C SSO SignOut Issue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

Recently I have Configured Azure AD B2C SSO in my project and now I am facing a sign out issue.

**Problem** - Out of 10 times 4 to 7 times I am able to logout successfully from the application and redirected to login page. **Once or twice (random behavior) after sign-out I am redirected to the home page (secured page).**

**Question** - I don't know how to replicate this issue or how to identify the exact cause and what would fix it?

My sign out code:

```cs
public ActionResult SignOut() {
    string[] myCookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
    foreach (string cookieKey in myCookies) {
        var responseCookie = HttpContext.Response.Cookies[cookieKey];
        if (responseCookie != null)
            responseCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    }
    Session.Abandon();
    try {
        var authTypes = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(authTypes.Select(t => t.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return RedirectToAction("SignIn");
    } catch {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
    }
}
```

**Findings** :

Fiddler

**Case** SignOut Success :

1. GET /Account/SignOut HTTP/1.1
2. GET /hostName/oauth2/v2.0/logout?p=b2c_1_passwordreset&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fhostName HTTP/1.1
3. GET /TenantId/oauth2/logout HTTP/1.1
4. Redirected to Login

**Case** SignOut UnSuccess :

1. GET /Account/SignOut HTTP/1.1
2. GET /hostName/oauth2/v2.0/logout?p=b2c_1_passwordreset&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fhostName HTTP/1.1
3. Redirected to Home Page

Comment: Catch the exception and include it in your question. As it stands, your question doesn't have nearly enough information for folks to be able to help you.

Comment: I have try catch but it never go to catch function. It means there is no exception for this API  call